# Is it necessary to use struts tags in form when using the validate function?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I read through the struts tutorial and was stuck a bit at struts validation(Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_validations.htm). I was wondering if its necessary to use struts tags when I wish to use the implicit validate() function provided by the struts framework. Is there any possible way using which I dont have to use the struts tags and still, I am allowed to use the implicit validate function along with the option 'addFieldError'?

I had tried to make a code for the same but it seems that we can not make use of 'addFieldError' unless we make use of struts tags completely in our form. Can anyone provide a little clarification on this?

Below is the code I tried, but the 'addFieldError' didnt work and the webpage got redirected directly to the page specified in 'struts.xml' where result was specified as "input"

```
/*public void validate()//Function to check implicit validations provided by Struts
{
    System.out.println("Inside implicit validate\n");
    if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("harshit"))
    {
        addFieldError("name","Only Harshit is allowed in name field");
    }
}*/
```

Sorry as I am not familiar with the formatting here.

Contents of struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>
<package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="hello"
    class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction"
    method="execute">
    <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Contents of Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

   <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Conetents of Index.jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validate()
{
    var empId= document.frm.empId.value;
    var name=document.frm.name.value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var email=document.frm.email.value;
    if(name=="")
        {
        //alert("Name should not be blank..");
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="Name shouldnt be blank";
        document.frm.name.focus();
        return false;
        }

    else if(empId=="")
        {
        alert("Employee ID should not be blank");
        document.frm.empId.focus();
        return false;
        }

    else if(isNaN(empId)==true)
        {
        alert("Employee ID should be a number");
        return false;
        }
    else if(!name.match(letters))
        {
        alert("Name should be an ablphabet");
        return false;
        }
    else if(!email.match(".com"))
        {
        alert("Please enter a valid email");
        return false;
        }
}
</script>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="beige">
   <h1>Employee Details</h1>

<form  action="hello" name="frm" onSubmit="return validate()">

      <label>Please enter your name</label><br/>

    <input type="text" name="name"/><font size="4" color="red"> <div id="error"> </div></font>

      <br/>
      <label>Employee ID:</label><br/>
       <input type="text" name="empId"/><br/>

       <label>Email Id:</label><br/>
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <br/>
       <label>Phone Number:</label><br/>
       <input type="text" name="phone">
       <br/>
       <br/>

       <br/>
       <input type= "button" value="Check" onclick="return validate()">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents of my Action Class

```
    package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;
    import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


    public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport
    {  
        private String name ;
        private String email;
        private long phone;
        private int empId;


        public int getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }
        public void setEmpId(int empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public long getPhone() {
            return phone;
        }
        public void setPhone(long phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


        public String execute() throws Exception
        {
            //String result=serverValidation();
            String result="success";//Temporarily making it success as the server validation is commented. Aim is to check the implicit validate method provided by struts
            return result;
        }

        /*public String serverValidation() throws Exception
        {
            long phnum= phone;
            System.out.println("Phone="+phone);
            System.out.println("phnum="+phnum);
            System.out.println("Employee Id=" +empId);
            int d=0;
            while(phnum>0)
            {
                phnum=phnum/10;
                d=d+1;
            }
            if(d==10)
            return "success";

            else
            {
                System.out.println("d="+d);
                return "error";
            }
        }*/

        public void validate()//Function to check implicit validations provided by Struts
        {
            System.out.println("Inside implicit validate\n");
            if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase("harshit"))
            {
                addFieldError("name","Only Harshit is allowed in name field");
            }
        }



}
```

Comment: Yes you can use S2 validation without S2 form tags.

Comment: @AleksandrM I provided the code used, Can you give me a little more clarification?

Comment: You need to display that error by yourself if you are not using S2 tags with xhtml/css_xhtml themes.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thank you but I can still do that without using the implicit validate() function provided. I can create a custom validate function for the same. But my aim is to try to use the implicit validate function along with the addErrorField option, so that I dont have to handle the error messages separately in <div> tag or use innerHTML in html or jsp pages

Comment: What do you mean? If `input` result is executed then `addFieldError` worked. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AleksandrM I am sorry if I am not clear enough. As shown above, I have used a method, to check the implicit struts validate() method. In struts.xml, (under result name="input")the call is sent to the index page. Though, the validate method is successful and on the if condition being true, the index page is called, but I am not able to see any error message which should be displayed as I am using addFieldError. Overall, I want to say that the validate function works fine but addFieldError does not display the required output. Instead, I am getting redirected to index page.

Comment: Are you using `redirectAction` result type? To show field error use  `<s:fielderror>` tag: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/fielderror.html.

Comment: He probably is. Please share your code... and the answer will probably be "use MessageStore Interceptor"

Comment: @AleksandrM That was my question in the first place. Can I use the implicit validate function without having to create my index page using struts form tags. Please find the code above :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios I am a newbie to struts and have just understood how the framework works, I'll look for further details about MessageStoreInterceptor. But, as suggested, I would wanna know if I dont have to use the struts tags at all to create a form and still be able to use the implicit validate() function. Thanks :)

Comment: The `<s:fielderror>` is not a *form* tag. And you need to use *some* taglib to show error (doesn't have to be S2). Think about it outside of S2 - How do you show some say string in the jsp?

Comment: Remove all your javascript, put s:fielderror. Leave MessageStore alone, it is used when you want to carry messages between two requests, for example when using redirectAction result.

Comment: @AleksandrM and Andrea Ligios

Thank you guys, <s:fielderror> worked. Sadly, it was not there in the tutorial which I went through but still, the guys had a screenshot of the expected outputs. Still in the learning phase, getting stuck at such things helps to figure out a lot. Thanks again to both of you :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios : not necessary to remove the javascripts, it still works fine :)

Comment: Ok, if you use it as a complementary client-side validation :)

Comment: How do I mark my question as answered :(?

Comment: @hchawla: You can answer your own question and then mark your answer as an accepted answer to the question.

Comment: @AleksandrM I understand that, but I didnt answer the question, you both did. So how do I give credit to you guys?

Comment: @hchawla: You still can write an answer and accept it to help future visitors with similar problems. As for the credit sometimes 'thank you' is enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AleksandrM and @AndreaLigios for providing the answer. Below is a little detailed description:

The implicit `validate()` method provided by Struts2 framework can be used even without having to use the Struts2 based form tags. All you need to do is use `<s:fielderror>` tag in the respective jsp/ html page where you want to display the error messages, followed by using the `<param>` tag to specify for which parameter, the error has to be displayed. The parameter name should be the same as used in the Action Class. Please refer the `validate()` method in the above code to see how the error messages are defined for a particular parameter. We can use the below snippet in the html/jsp to display the error message:

```
<s:fielderror>
    <s:param> name</s:param>
</s:fielderror>
```

Here, `name` is the parameter for which validation has been done.

Comment: Note: you can use `fieldName` attribute (e.g. `<s:fielderror fieldName="name" />`) instead of param tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks again for improving the answer :)